# 'factors with the same levels' in Confusion Matrix

Tags: r, decision-tree, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to make a decision tree but this error comes up when I make a confusion matrix in the last line :

```
Error : `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels
```

Here's my code:

```
library(rpart)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(rpart.plot)
library(xlsx)
library(caTools)
library(data.tree)
library(e1071)

#Loading the Excel File
library(readxl)
FINALDATA <- read_excel("Desktop/FINALDATA.xlsm")
View(FINALDATA)
df <- FINALDATA
View(df)

#Selecting the meaningful columns for prediction
#df <- select(df, City, df$`Customer type`, Gender, Quantity, Total, Date, Time, Payment, Rating)
df <- select(df, City, `Customer type`, Gender, Quantity, Total, Date, Time, Payment, Rating)

#making sure the data is in the right format 
df <- mutate(df, City= as.character(City), `Customer type`= as.character(`Customer type`), Gender= as.character(Gender), Quantity= as.numeric(Quantity), Total= as.numeric(Total), Time= as.numeric(Time), Payment = as.character(Payment), Rating= as.numeric(Rating))

#Splitting into training and testing data
set.seed(123)
sample = sample.split('Customer type', SplitRatio = .70)
train = subset(df, sample==TRUE)
test = subset(df, sample == FALSE)

#Training the Decision Tree Classifier
tree <- rpart(df$`Customer type` ~., data = train)

#Predictions
tree.customertype.predicted <- predict(tree, test, type= 'class')

#confusion Matrix for evaluating the model
confusionMatrix(tree.customertype.predicted, test$`Customer type`)
```

So I've tried to do this as said in another topic:

```
confusionMatrix(table(tree.customertype.predicted, test$`Customer type`))
```

But I still have an error:

```
Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : argument type is invalid
```

Comment: Just to follow up. In cases where you have a large data file, it's possible to create a sample data set that reproduces your problem.  Here is some [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how people do that. Having the data makes it much easier for the community to help you.

Comment: Thank you ! I will apply the guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a toy data set and examined your code. There were a couple issues:

1. R has a easier time with variable names that follow a certain style.  Your 'Customer type' variable has a space in it. In general, coding is easier when you avoid spaces. So I renamed it 'Customer_type". For your data.frame you could simply go into the source file, or use `names(df) <- gsub("Customer type", "Customer_type", names(df))`.
2. I coded 'Customer_type' as a factor. For you this will look like `df$Customer_type <- factor(df$Customer_type)`
3. The documentation for `sample.split()` says the first argument 'Y' should be a vector of labels.  But in your code you gave the variable name.  The labels are the names of the ***levels*** of the factor. In my example these levels are High, Med and Low. To see the levels of your variable you could use `levels(df$Customer_type)`. Input these to `sample.split()` as a character vector.
4. Adjust the `rpart()` call as shown below.

With these adjustments, your code might be OK.

```
# toy data
df <- data.frame(City = factor(sample(c("Paris", "Tokyo", "Miami"), 100, replace = T)),
                 Customer_type = factor(sample(c("High", "Med", "Low"), 100, replace = T)),
                 Gender = factor(sample(c("Female", "Male"), 100, replace = T)),
                 Quantity = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
                 Total = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
                 Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 100),
                 Rating = factor(sample(1:5, 100, replace = T)))

library(rpart)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(caTools)
library(data.tree)
library(e1071)

#Splitting into training and testing data
set.seed(123)
sample = sample.split(levels(df$Customer_type), SplitRatio = .70) # ADJUST YOUR CODE TO MATCH YOUR FACTOR LABEL NAMES
train = subset(df, sample==TRUE)
test = subset(df, sample == FALSE)

#Training the Decision Tree Classifier
tree <- rpart(Customer_type ~., data = train) # ADJUST YOUR CODE SO IT'S LIKE THIS

#Predictions
tree.customertype.predicted <- predict(tree, test, type= 'class')

#confusion Matrix for evaluating the model
confusionMatrix(tree.customertype.predicted, test$Customer_type)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I did what you said. Before splitting/training the data I've extracted labels from data to create a vector of data labels like this : customerlabel <- c(df$Customer_type, recursive = FALSE, use.names = TRUE). I input it in the sample.split function : sample = sample.split(customerlabel, SplitRatio = .70), test$Customer_type). Even though the accuracy is only 0,47, it's fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep factor levels of `train` and `test` same as `df`.

```
train$`Customer type` <- factor(train$`Customer type`, unique(df$`Customer type`))
test$`Customer type` <- factor(test$`Customer type`, unique(df$`Customer type`))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I place those lines after :

'train = subset(df, sample==TRUE)
test = subset(df, sample == FALSE)'

However when i make my confusion matrix, I have 4 zeros and an accuracy of 'NaN'